# Rate time limit error during search operation

Tags: java, twitter4j

When I tried to get public tweets using twitter4j by searching keywords like (sports +exclude:retweets), I get the following error:

```
420:Returned by the Search and Trends API when you are being rate limited (https:
    //dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting).
    Returned by the Streaming API:
     Too many login attempts in a short period of time.
     Running too many copies of the same application authenticating with the same acc
    ount name.
    {"error":"You have been rate limited. Enhance your calm."}
    Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
            http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=d35baff5 or
            http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0877c84f
    TwitterException{exceptionCode=[d35baff5-0877c84f], statusCode=420, retryAfter=51
    1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.6}
            at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:185

    - Unable to search keyword = Query{query='sports OR +exclude:retweets', lang='n
    ull', locale='null', maxId=-1, rpp=-1, page=15, since='null', sinceId=-1, geocode
    ='null', until='null', resultType='null'} You have been rate limited. Enhance your calm
```

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this even when I am only doing a search operation? Is there something wrong with the API?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are being rate-limited as the error says. Are you running this too many times in a row? Are you connecting more often than needed?